# Send data to Android device Notification to IOS devices

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

We are using firebase to send notifications to both Android and IOS devices from server and we are using **legacy FCM to send notifications**.
But when our app is backgrounded notification is handled by system itself and thus we couldn't handle it by app. So we need to add data to notification to handle the notification by application itself on android side.

But due to we also have ios devices we couldn't remove notification from the pattern.

Is there any way to send data to Android devices and notification to IOS devices?

Also you may find the pattern that I mentioned at below.

```
{
    {
    "registration_ids":[

    ],
    "content_available":true,
    "priority":"high",
    "data":{
        "title":"",
        "text":"",
        "badge": 1,
        "sound": "default"
    },
    "notification":{
        "title":"",
        "body":"",
        "badge": 1,
        "sound": "default"
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to do the same implementation, Did you get any solution for  above question?

Answer (score -2):

You will have to map the `FCM Registration ID` with the `OS Type` and store it somehow. Now when you are sending the notifications, based on the `OS Type`, you will change the body structure for the notifications.